# Typescript error with custom Typography component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have created a rather basic typography component for my React application and it's throwing a Typescript error which i must admit is baffling my slightly.

**Typography Component Code**

```
import clsx from 'clsx';

const variants = {
    h1: 'h1',
    h2: 'h2',
    h3: 'h2',
    h4: 'h2',
    h5: 'h2',
    h6: 'h2',
    subheading1: 'h6',
    subheading2: 'h6',
    body1: 'p',
    body2: 'p',
    link: 'p',
};

const typographyVariants = {
    h1: 'text-6xl',
    h2: 'text-5xl',
    h3: 'text-4xl',
    h4: 'text-3xl',
    h5: 'text-2xl',
    h6: 'text-1xl',
    subheading1: 'text-1xl font-bold',
    subheading2: 'text-1xl font-semibold',
    body1: 'text-base',
    body2: 'text-base font-bold',
    link: 'text-xs text-primaryViolet uppercase underline font-bold',
};

export type TypographyProps = {
    variant?: keyof typeof variants;
    className?: string;
    children: React.ReactNode | string;
};

export const Typography = ({ variant = 'body1', className, children }: TypographyProps) => {
    const Component = variants[variant];
    const typographyStyles = typographyVariants[variant];

    return (
        <Component className={clsx('font-sans', typographyStyles, className)}>{children}</Component>
    );
};
```

**Typescript Error**

The '<Component' bit in the return statment is highlighted with the following error

Type '{ children: ReactNode; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Lee

Comment: So, `Component` is actually a native HTML element name? Have you tried wrapping the `h1`, `h2` etc. in actual components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const variants = {
    h1: 'h1',
    h2: 'h2',
    h3: 'h2',
    h4: 'h2',
    h5: 'h2',
    h6: 'h2',
    subheading1: 'h6',
    subheading2: 'h6',
    body1: 'p',
    body2: 'p',
    link: 'p',
};
```

With no explicit type on this, typescript assigns `string` to all the properties, which means `Component` in `const Component = variants[variant];` is also of type `string`. With a type that general, the only things you're allowed to pass in to `<Component />` are ones that are shared by every single element. This is represented by a type called `IntrinsicAttributes`, and is just the `key` property. No children allowed, no className allowed.

You can fix this by being more explicit when defining `variants`. The simplest approach would just be to add `as const` to the end, so that typescript will be stricter in the definition that it infers:

```
const variants = {
    h1: 'h1',
    // ...
    link: 'p',
} as const;
```

With that change, `Component` now has the type `"h1" | "h2" | "h6" | "p"`, and since all of those elements allow children and className, the type error will go away.